# accept attribute is not working in <s:file> tag of struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I am trying to validate the content types of uploading files using  accept attribute but it seem to be not working.
Here is my code.

```
<s:file theme="simple" name="fileUpload" accept="image/jpeg"/>
```

i also tried

```
<s:file theme="simple" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*"/>
```

Both are not working what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML `accept` attribute is not supported in IE and Safari. You can define allowed mime types in `struts.xml` for you file upload action like that:

```
<action name="..." class="...">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
     <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">image/jpeg</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result>...</result>
</action>
```

See others parameters you can configure in [`fileUpload`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html) interceptor.